# Custom font can be used in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, uistoryboard

Is there any way to use custom font in storyboard? Intention here is to cover components styling through storyboard itself and will reflect the font.So that I can change from FontA to FontB from a single place. I know it can be done through code but constraint is lot of UI is designed in storyboard and many outlets are not created.

I am just wondering if it is possible?

Comment: @Sateesh Question was different to the mentioned answer. So it is not duplicate. And I wanted to change font at runtime or from a single place through configuration class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two approaches that we found in our way:
1. Using method swizzling
2. Creating category for UIFont and override the methods

```
#import "SystemFontOverride.h"

@implementation UIFont (SystemFontOverride)

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"
// do your override
+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-Regular" size:fontSize];
    if (font != nil) {
        return font;
    }
    return [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
}

+ (UIFont *)boldSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-Bold" size:fontSize];
    if (font != nil) {
        return font;
    }
    return [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
}
+ (UIFont *)italicSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-Italic" size:fontSize];
    if (font != nil) {
        return font;
    }
    return [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
}

+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize weight:(UIFontWeight)weight NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_2) {
    NSString *fontName;
    if (weight == UIFontWeightSemibold) {
        fontName = @"Raleway-SemiBold";
    } else if (weight == UIFontWeightBold) {
        fontName = @"Raleway-Bold";
    } else if (weight == UIFontWeightRegular){
        fontName = @"Raleway-Regular";
    } else if (weight == UIFontWeightMedium){
        fontName = @"Raleway-Medium";
    } else if (weight == UIFontWeightThin){
        fontName = @"Raleway-Thin";
    } else if (weight == UIFontWeightBlack) {
        fontName = @"Raleway-Black";
    }
    if (fontName != nil && fontName.length > 0) {
        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];
        if (font != nil) {
            return font;
        }
    }
    return [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
    {
        if (self) {
            BOOL result = [coder containsValueForKey:@"UIFontDescriptor"];
            if (result) {
                UIFontDescriptor *descriptor = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"UIFontDescriptor"];

                NSString *fontName;
                if ([descriptor.fontAttributes[@"NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute"] isEqualToString:@"CTFontRegularUsage"]) {
                    fontName = @"Raleway-Regular";
                }
                else if ([descriptor.fontAttributes[@"NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute"] isEqualToString:@"CTFontEmphasizedUsage"]) {
                    fontName = @"Raleway-Bold";
                }
                else if ([descriptor.fontAttributes[@"NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute"] isEqualToString:@"CTFontObliqueUsage"]) {
                    fontName = @"Raleway-Italic";
                }
                else {
                    fontName = descriptor.fontAttributes[@"NSFontNameAttribute"];
                }
                return [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:descriptor.pointSize];
            }
        }
        return self;
    }


#pragma clang diagnostic pop
@end
```

Another catch was to override the systemFont which are set in storyboard we needed to implement initWithCoder.

Thanks for all your answers above but I found this way more effective and full coverage in less time. Now I can create my font enum and can set whatever I want to change without bothering about whether I have set font from storyboard or code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, custom fonts can be used within the storyboard.

1. Add the Font file to your Xcode project.
2. Register your font in the `Info.plist`:

```
UIAppFonts : 
Item 0 : MyCustomFont.ttf
```

Your font should now show up in the Storyboard.

Please refer to the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app?language=objc) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use custom fonts with storyboard.

Follow these steps :

- Include your fonts in your XCode project.
- Make sure that they’re included in the target.
- Double check that your fonts are included as Resources in your bundle.
- Include your iOS custom fonts in your application plist.
- Find the name of the font.

  You can find name of font with below code snippet:

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   for family: String in UIFont.familyNames
    {
      print(family)
      for names: String in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
      {
         print("== \(names)")
      }
     }
   }
  ```
- Now you can use this font name and set font from storyboard.

Check this : https://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

It might help you.

Comment: I will have to change font name everywhere manually if I have to change the font.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use them from storyboards. Add your custom font files to app resources and mention them in info.plist. Here I am adding bwnistageometricdemo-regular to info.plist.

`<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>bwnistageometricdemo-regular.ttf</string>
    </array>`

And you can use it from storyboard like -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my question was different.